# how to get the values from fieldset using javascript?

Tags: javascript, forms

```html
<form action="welcome.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validate();">
<fieldset>
<legend> <b>Personal Info</b> </legend>
<pre>
<b>First Name</b> <input type="text" id="fname" size="30">
<b>Last Name</b> <input type="text" id="lname" size="30">
<b>Phone Number</b> <input type="number" id="fn" size="30">
    <fieldset>
    <legend> <b>Gender</b> </legend>
    <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="Male">Male
    <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="Female">Female
    </fieldset>
</pre>
</fieldset>
<input type="button" value="submit">
</form>
```

JavaScript function is validate(). If First name or Last name or Gender is empty, user will see a message and form will not submit. By using JavaScript function what will be the solution?

Comment: Are you asking how to do `getElementById("fname").value`?

Comment: function valid()
{
    var fname = document.getElementById('fname').value;
    var lname = document.getElementById('lname').value;
    if(fname == "" || lname == "")
    {
        alert('Please insert your name');
        return false;
    }
    return true;

}

i tried this way..bt it is nt working

Comment: Please update your question, code in comments is hard to read.

Comment: You're calling a function `validate()` but you defined the function `valid()`.

Comment: i correct that many times ago bt may be my xampp is nt properly working.....!!bt tnx..

Comment: Your function looks fine to me. Set breakpoints or add alerts to see what the values of the variables are.

Comment: is this still really open

Answer (score 0):

Note: Use id to get the component value rather than depending on fieldset.

Here html code goes...

```
<form name="myForm" action="demo_form.asp" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
First name: <input type="text" name="fname">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Here validation goes... return false will avoid sending request to backend.
If you won't use form name, then use `document.getElementById(<id name>).value` to get the value

```
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("First name must be filled out");
  return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

By using jquery you can get all the input values

Example:

```
var fname= $('#fname').val();
var lname= $('#lname').val();
```

Adding Required Attr to Input fields makes validation

```
<form action="welcome.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validate();">
<fieldset>
<legend> <b>Personal Info</b> </legend>
<pre>
<b>First Name</b> <input type="text" id="fname" required size="30">
<b>Last Name</b> <input type="text" id="lname" required size="30">
<b>Phone Number</b> <input type="number" id="fn" required size="30">
    <fieldset>
    <legend> <b>Gender</b> </legend>
    <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="Male">Male
    <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="Female">Female
    </fieldset>
</pre>
</fieldset>
<input type="button" value="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score -2):

Why are you worrying about the field set, every element is having an id, so you can directly go for getting element with id.

```
document.getElementById("id-here")
```